# Having a hard time finding a way to follow a path

Tags: html, css

I've been working on doing things like Codeacademy, trying to do minor projects on my own like designing a website, and also searching around the web for simple projects to work on to gain more experience. The issue has been that I'm having a hard time finding a good curriculum to follow in terms of learning what I need to learn in order to perform well when working in the development of websites or apps. Do any of you have any tips on any websites I could follow a set guide or anything of that nature to help me better my work? Most of them teach you the start of it and after that they say you have to pay or you have to sign up for a course to continue.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. My honest advice, if you haven't done so already, is to start by learning the basics of storing and manipulating data in a relational database (e.g. mySQL, or even Access as a start point). There is no substitute for a good knowledge of SQL. I would recommend this textbook: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Inside-Relational-Databases-Examples-Access/dp/1846283949/ref=la_B001JP2HAQ_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1553276424&sr=1-2 but there are loads of good ones out there.

Comment: What interests you? Try to build it yourself. It doesnt matter if you reference other peoples code, thats fine. The wholeprocess will have you learn. For example when i wanted to learn how to build web apps with Reactjs. I built my own url shortener, todo app, and then blog. Each one taught me something different and it built on the knowledge of the past project. Good luck.

Comment: @MandyShaw Thank you for letting me know about SQL, I'll look into it more. Sadly, I am extremely poor and I'm trying to learn these things to improve my situation so I can't afford books on amazon. I will check the library though for this.

Comment: @MattPengelly I do paintings with my girlfriend, so I could work on a website that displays the artwork, would that be something that could be beneficial?

Comment: @OregonNelson Of course. If you make something yourself, you're forced to think about what is involved. For example if you wanted this site to be dynamic and easily updatable if you guys make new art then youd probably end up with a different solution then if you just wanted the site to remain the same forever. Like maybe youd want a login system for whatever reason or a subscribe feature so people can get updates automatically when you release new artwork. both of those things require you to think about how you would implement something specific. IE: login or a subscribe features.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you're going through as I was in your shoes an year back. I would suggest you to follow the tutorial series of Python and then Django by *Corey Schafer* on YouTube. They are completely free and highly informative. You may start with Python beginners tutorial if you're completely unfamiliar with Python. After this, you can follow the Django series in which you'll learn to build a blogging website. As you said that you've been doing minor projects on your own so there won't be much difficulty in understanding the HTML and CSS used for the front end.
Here's the link to the YouTube channel I mentioned-
https://www.youtube.com/user/schafer5

I hope that this gives you an edge in your learning process.
Good luck mate!

Comment: I will look into these videos, knowing more can't hurt! I haven't had an interest in Python sadly. I will try to learn it though, even if it's the basics since having more knowledge is always good.

Comment: Do mention your interests and what kind of projects have you been doing or are willing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you [Udemy](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj21remspbhAhUMso8KHeHHD1wQFjAAegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw3NZJ-fsjWkq7vrq7FteHy6), which is a perfect collection for learning all sorts of technical studies. I learned **Android programming**, **.NET**, and **Unity 3D** from **Udemy**, and really it is helpful.
You may need to purchase the courses, maybe $10-15. But it is worth a shot.